# Problem with creating a new database

Tags: asp.net, sql, profiling

When I try to create a new database with asp.net sql server setup wizard it connects to my local server and creates a database with all the tables from all the databases that exist in the local machine. But I want a new aspnetdb database with empty tables for profiling.

UPDATE :

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -C<Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Profiling\App_Data\Membership.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True> -S<DIMA-00AA1DA557>
```

I have no userid and password..sorry it tells me ..syntax is wrong

Comment: See my update on my answer to fix the syntax issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the tables, but no data, for aspnetdb.  Run the following command in a command (DOS) window:

`aspnet_regsql.exe`

For example:

`aspnet_regsql.exe -C<connectionstring> -S<servername> -U<userid> -P<password>`

Where `<connectionstring>`, `<servername>`, `<userid>` and `<password>` are filled in by you with your specific information.  Remove the `<` and `>` from the parameters I listed to fix your incorrect syntax error.

[ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has all the details.

**UPDATE**

If you can log in to the server (with your Windows credentials), try this with the -E switch.  I'm not sure you can attach a database with this, but it can't hurt to try.

`apsnet_regsql.exe -CData Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Profiling\App_Data\Membership.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True -SDIMA-00AA1DA557 -E`

**UPDATE 2**

According to the documentation linked above, the -C option is not required if you specify -U and -P or -E.  So, **assuming your windows credentials allow you access** to the SDIMA-00AA1DA557 server, try this:

`aspnet_regsql.exe -E -SDIMA-00AA1DA557`

Comment: it told me the syntax is incorrect..why is it so hard to create a new profiling database??!?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard.  Try the command again, and if you get the same error, please update your question with both the command (and parameters) you used and the error message it gave you.

Comment: The way you described is way way way too convoluted..and i doubt it would work.. I want a new database with aspdbnet tables in it..empty as new

Comment: Convoluted how?  You run the command and it creates a brand spanking new aspnetdb with no data in the tables (i.e., empty tables).  I fail to see how that is convoluted, and I assure you it does work, as I've done it in the past.

Comment: are you telling that each time i want to attach a single database file that i have got ...asp.net will attach a unified database with all the tables from all hte databases that exist on my local machine????? and then i have to follow your method.

Comment: If you're copying from a window (like notepad or the web), select the text, push ctrl-c, then go to the Command window and right-click and select paste.

Comment: i havent even got a userid and a password. i do have a server name..and no idea what the connectio nstring is

Comment: If you have access to the SQL server, you can use the -E switch in place of the -U and -P switches.  As far as the connection string, if you have access to the box you should be able to build the connection string.

Comment: this is so hard..what do i need to type again..(see also the update).. and i dont know what all the "switches" above ..mean..what box?

Comment: it would never work...the explanation htat you gave is so so bad

Comment: The explanation I gave is so bad?  Hello pot, this is kettle speaking.  Did you even read the information at the link I posted in my original answer?

Comment: what do you want me to put in the connection string anyway..the connection string belongs to an already created database

Comment: See my 2nd update for a way to do it with only the server name specified and windows credentials for the logged-on user (that would be you).

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with Tim, you need to use command-line registration tool.
Additionaly (to make sure) check 'model' database on your local SQL server. Each new databse by default contains all objects from 'model' database.

Comment: System database 'model' exists on every ms sql server. You can find it using SQL Server Management Studio in Databases->System Databases

Comment: Why when i create every databaswe..it adds old tables belonging to other databases :(

Comment: Try to execute `CREATE DATABASE [new_test_DB];` in your SQL Server. Then look at the objects in this [new_test_DB] database.